# JetBrains IDEA: Change color of code completion menu selection highlight in Darcula LAF

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Darcula and I are struggling to come to terms. Legibility is poor overall but some things I just have to change:

[image: screenshot]

In this code completion suggestion menu, the selected item is not legible.

Where in the preferences or preferences XML file is the background color of the selected item text set?

Comment: That could be a system-specific configuration setting.  What OS are you running this on?

Comment: @Makoto osx. where are the system-specific configuration settings located?

Answer (score 10):

You can find the option to change the color of the code auto completion window from the following place.

`Open your settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Popups and Hints > Completion.`

Note: you may also search for the keyword `completion` in the settings page to find the option fast.

Then adjust the background color and click apply.

You can check the screenshot for a visual reference.

[image]

Comment: Option not available in `2019` releases (and any older).

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this 3 days ago. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103104
Now it looks like this
[idea completion http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/6516/ss20130319202811.png](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/6516/ss20130319202811.png)

Comment: Was that a change to the LAF or to the color scheme?

Comment: That was a problem with custom painting in completion popup component

Answer (score 0):

I solved this probleme by downloading a new INTELLIJ THEME named Gradianto and it works nice,

Gradianto allows you to chose beetween 3 darcula theme once it's installed in your intellij, and all of this theme will highlight the selected item clearly with code completion.

Yous install the theme with :
IntellijIDEA --> Preferences --> Plugins --> And you search and install Gradianto theme

Here is the youtube tutoriel where i see it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsZZm5f5JD0

Hope that will help

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I got a nice answer to your question.

This is link : [java - Changing the font colour in IDEA code-completion window - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283638/changing-the-font-colour-in-idea-code-completion-window)

```
You just need unable this option : 

[ 
Settings —— Editor —— Code Completion 
—— Insert selected variant by typing dot , space ,etc . 
]

No doubt of it , it works very well for me !
```