# Changing the font colour in IDEA code-completion window

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I was wondering, how do I change the font colour in the code-completion window in IntelliJ IDEA? The default font is grey and, despite changing almost every font colour in the application settings, I am stuck with grey (which is very hard to read).

I'm talking about this window: [image: IDEA's statement-completion font colour]

Does anyone know how to change this statement-completion font colour to black?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enable the *Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc.* option to get the old behavior.

[image: Settings dialog]

[Check this discussion](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101526) for more details:

> The purpose is to disable selection by dot/space/etc by default and to be able to distinguish this mode visually.
>
> ...
>
> If you love dots and spaces, you can return to the old mode via
> Settings | Editor | Code completion.
>
> There seems to be a need to distinguish the modes because you might
> want to choose a non-first item, or to choose the first one by typing
> some non-orthodox symbol (e.g. exclamation mark). In this case, you
> press Up/Down to navigate in the list and after that there seems to be
> no reason for space or exclamation mark not to select the current
> item. Having two modes which behave differently but look exactly the
> same doesn't seem like a great idea to me from the perspective of user
> interaction design.

Comment: Ouch ! Sir, this is a amazing solution ! It looks like not related . But it solved my problem !