# How to change autocomplete highlight color in Rider

Tags: intellij-idea, themes, rider

I am using Gruvbox Dark Hard Theme

[image: Autocompletion Color]

The color of text that matched the autocomplete is almost invisible

How do I change the foreground color of this matched text?

I have also found some solution related to IntelliJ Editor family [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283638/changing-the-font-colour-in-idea-code-completion-window) which does not seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment the primary way to change it is through UI theme plugins.

It can also be changed through internal LaF editor, but just for a single session (will gone after restarting IDE):

1. Add "-Didea.is.internal=true" in "Help | Edit Custom VM options" and restart IDE
2. Open "Find Action" popup and search for "LaF defaults" dialog
3. Edit "CompletionPopup.matchForeground" property:

[image: CompletionPopup.matchForeground property in "Edit LaF defaults" dialog]

Comment: you said it could be done using UI theme plugins, can you explain?

Comment: You can create theme plugin and customise the aforementioned keys through "*.theme.json" file: https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/ui_themes/themes_customize.html